# Looping over an array inside an if statement in Pug template

Tags: pug

I have an each loop inside an if statement that refuses to work. I'm doing exactly the same thing with a different set of data which does work, and the only difference I can ascertain between the two sets, is that if I dump to the screen, the non-functional set is contained within square brackets [] - js says both sets are objects.

This is my code:

```
 - if(framework === 'framework')
        .form__group 
            label=`${frameworkOptions}` \\ this outputs the array to the screen and looks ok to me
            select
                - if(frameworkOptions && frameworkOptions.length > 0)
                    each frameworkOption in frameworkOptions
                            option(value=`${frameworkOption._id}`)=`${frameworkOption.text}` 
                - else
                        option(disabled)=`No Options available`
```

Strangely (to me), if I remove "&& frameworkOptions.length > 0" I get a very long list of 'undefineds'. Otherwise it just shows the 'else' (No options).

Am I looping incorrectly? Is it because it's an array and I need to do something different?

Comment: you have an  indentation issue in `option`

Comment: Are you sure `frameworkOptions` is an array and not a string that looks like an array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up the syntax of ES6 and pug. Try it like this:

```
if framework === 'framework'
    .form__group 
        - label=frameworkOptions
        select
            if frameworkOptions && frameworkOptions.length > 0
                each frameworkOption in frameworkOptions
                    option(value=frameworkOption._id)= frameworkOption.text
            else
                option(disabled=true) No Options available
```